# Distribution check - different results using plt.hist and seaborn.displot

Tags: python, distribution, seaborn, histogram

I have an apparently very simple task: checking the distribution of values contained in an array `data`. Only thing is, I get two completely different results by plotting the said distribution using two different methods. Here are the PDF and the CDF, computed and plotted using two different methods:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = #myarray
print(np.mean(data), np.var(data))

[OUT]: 55418588.339231685 1.42543704496229e+18

plt.hist(data, bins=100, density=True, alpha=0.6, color='b', log = False) #pdf
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
plt.plot(np.cumsum(data), drawstyle='steps') #cdf
plt.show()
```

[image: result using matplotlib's histogram]

```
sns.displot(data, log_scale=True, kind = 'kde') #pdf
sns.displot(data, log_scale=True, kind = 'ecdf') #cdf
```

[image: result using seaborn's displot]

The second result seems quite close to a Gaussian to me, which by the way would be a very unusual result given the nature of the experimental data, but this is irrelevant to the question now. Matplotlib's result instead seems much more a heavy left-tailed.

I am sure I am doing something wrong, either in the interpretation or in the execution, but I don't know where. I'd love some help in understanding what I am doing differently between the two attempts.

Comment: cumsum(data) is *not* the ecdf.   And when you plot a histogram it chooses the bins on some rule of thumb of the data; when you do this on original scale, but then change the visualization x-axis to log scale, you end up with a only very few (a single?) bin.

General advice: don't use histograms for continuous data, but KDE estimates (like displot).  histograms obfuscate information in continous data; density plots and ECDF plots (especially for heavy-tailed , right skewed or zero-inflated data) are much more informative than histograms can ever be.

Comment: also suggest to use https://github.com/gmgeorg/pylambertw for quick visualization of normality of data (see readme and the `test_norm()` plot method)